# 遺伝的アルゴリズムは四則演算のみでも実装できますか？

Tags: アルゴリズム

通常遺伝的アルゴリズムは交配でビット演算を利用しますが、ビット演算によって四則演算が実現できているので、四則演算のみでも遺伝的アルゴリズムは実現できると考えました。この考えは間違っていますか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ビットシフトは乗算と除算、ビットマスクは剰余で代替可能ではないでしょうか。また遺伝的アルゴリズムでは個体をビット列ではなく数値の構造体として表現することも可能です。